# How to account for multi-locale localization in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Consider the following tables:

Table: Item

```
[Id], [Description]
1     'Item 1 Description'
2     'Item 2 Description'
3     'Item 3 Description'
```

Table: ItemLocalization

```
[Id], [ItemId], [Culture], [Description]
1     1         'es'       'This item 1 spanish description'
2     1         'es-AR'    'This item 1 spanish argentina description'
```

So here is my query:

```
DECLARE @Culture NVARCHAR(10) = 'el-cl'

SELECT I.[Id],
    ISNULL(NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(IL.[Description])), ''), I.[Description]) AS [Description]
FROM [Item] I
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [ItemLocalization] IL ON IL.[ItemId] = I.[Id] AND IL.[Culture] = @Culture
```

The above code will give me the item id and description of the specific culture I ask it for. If there is no culture then it will fallback to the default from the main table. However, in the above scenario I do not have `es-cl` but I do have `es` and I want it to fall back to `es`.

1. How can I further modify the query to tell it to grab the `es` because there is no `es-cl`.
2. How can I ensure to still get 'es-ar' if I pass that as a culture and not grab es?

   3. How can I ensure to still get 'es' if there is only es in the database and I pass a culture such as `es-ar`

The only thing I thought was to break apart the culture and grab first 2 values, but I still can't figure out how to turn it into a single query.

EDIT: If the solution requires changing the input such as maybe splitting culture into two variables, that would be ok too.

Final Edit:

What Gordon put as his answer is correct for all of my scenarios. However, I did find his solution to be a bit too long as I have to apply this on pretty much every table and wanted to simplify further. I also wanted to account to fallback to english without having so many ISNULL checks. In the end my final solution involves removing the description field from table `Item` and adding a new field called `DefaultCulture` to table `ItemLocalization`. By having that I can do the following:

```
DECLARE @Culture NVARCHAR(10) = 'el-cl'

SELECT TOP 1 I.[Id], IL.[Description]
FROM [Item] I
    INNER JOIN [ItemLocalization] IL ON IL.[ItemId] = I.[Id] AND (@Culture LIKE CONCAT(IL.[Culture], '%') OR (IL.[Culture] LIKE CONCAT(@Culture, '%')) OR IL.[DefaultCulture] = 1)
ORDER BY IL.[DefaultCulture] ASC, [Culture] DESC
```

The reason this works is because I first sort by `DefaultCulture` in ASC order meaning that default culture will always go to the bottom. Then I sort by `Culture` in DESC order so that the longest name shows up at the top. As my solution was heavily inspired by Gordon's answer (and he did provide a solution to my question at the time), I have marked his correct and provided my final solution here in question for future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
DECLARE @Culture NVARCHAR(10) = 'el-cl'

SELECT I.[Id],
       COALESCE(NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(IL.[Description])), ''), I.[Description]) AS [Description]
FROM [Item] I OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) IL.*
      FROM [ItemLocalization] IL 
      WHERE IL.[ItemId] = I.[Id] AND
            @Culture LIKE IL.[Culture] + '%'
      ORDER BY LEN(IL.[Culture]) DESC
     ) IL;
```

This returns the longest `Culture` where `@Culture` starts with the same characters.

Comment: Using length, quite clever! Didn't think of that. The only concern I have is if @Culture is lets say `el-cl` and the database only has `el` then it would not find a match. Or maybe I am wrong? I also started playing with the idea of breaking it into two parameters as oppose to one. So `el` would be one parameter and `cl` would be another.

Comment: @Bojan . . . Perhaps you should ask a *new* question with a clear description of the logic and the different scenarios to describe what you want.

Comment: I thought I described that scenario, I read over the question and I see it is not so clear. I updated the question.

Comment: I finally had time to thoroughly test your example and it accounts for the scenario I mentioned before. It finds `es` if I pass something like `es-CL` and when `es-CL` does not exists. It will also find `es-CL` instead of `es` if it does exist.

Answer (score -2):

@Bojan, can you try This (Fixed) :

```
DECLARE @Id As Int = 1
DECLARE @Culture NVARCHAR(10) = 'es-cl'

Select 
I.Id,
(
    Select Top(1) Tx.Description 
    FROM 
    (
        Select IL.[Description]
        FROM [ItemLocalization] IL 
        Where IL.[ItemId] = I.[Id] 
        AND IL.[Culture] = @Culture

        Union All

        Select IL.[Description]
        FROM [ItemLocalization] IL 
        Where IL.[ItemId] = I.[Id] 
        AND IL.[Culture] = 'es'

        Union All

        Select IL.[Description]
        FROM [ItemLocalization] IL 
        Where IL.[ItemId] = I.[Id] 
        AND IL.[Culture] = 'es-AR'


    ) As TX

) As Description

FROM [Item] I
Where I.Id = @Id
```